# Trouble with Model Push Behaviour on Ratchet with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, websocket, ratchet

I'm having some trouble getting the Model Push Behaviour to work using WyriHaximus' CakePHP plugin for Ratchet: https://github.com/WyriHaximus/Ratchet

I've installed it, got the server working, and connected to it. But whenever I add Push behaviour to the Model, it gives me a Missing Behaviour error, because the Plugin doesn't contain one. However it has a sister plugin which does.

I've tried merging the two, but I think it's designed to run in tandem with it. So I'm at a loss.

In my model I've got:

```
public $actsAs = array(
        'Ratchet.Pushable' => array(
            'events' => array(
                array(
                    'eventName' => 'WyriProject.created',
                    'created' => true,
                ),
            ),
        ), 
    );
```

Everything's bootstrapped, loaded, it's just not speaking to the other plugin. Anyone had any experience getting this working?

Answer (score 1):

WyriHaximus' documentation is a bit rusty. I ran into the same problem last week and got the behavior working as follows:

1. Add `wyrihaximus/ratchet-commands` and `wyrihaximus/ratchet-model-push` using Composer. ([how to add composer dependencies](http://ceeram.github.io/blog/2013/02/22/using-composer-with-cakephp-2-dot-x/))
2. Instead of `$actAs = [ 'Ratchet.Pushable' => [ ... ] ]`, use `$actAs = [ 'RatchetModelPush.Pushable' => [ ... ] ]`

Comment: Qwertman - Can you post any more links/turorials/documentation that explain specifically how to configure Ratchet in CakePHP using this plugin? Thanks for the good answer, it helped me make progress.

Comment: After I saw the server-side code and learned how Ratchet works, I ended up abandoning this path. It essentially runs a service alongside your CakePHP, which receives local messages from Cake and then relays them to the front-end through web-sockets (the frontend connects to the service rather than Cake for sockets). I figured if it's a ridealong process anyways, I might as well make that a Node.JS process so that I can use the modern and straightforward Socket.IO. It's worked out pretty well - seeing how many others are trying to do Cake WS on SO, I'll have to make a how-to blog post on it.

Comment: Mussser, I've written about a non-Ratchet alternative here: http://maxpittsley.com/plug-in-the-cake-retrofitting-a-cakephp-app-with-web-sockets/